# Does $\mathbb{CP}^2$ admit an exotic smooth structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

After some searching, I found [this paper](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~akhmedov/akhmedov-park-braided.pdf) which claims that $\mathbb{CP}^2\#2\overline{\mathbb{CP}}^2$ has the smallest Euler characteristic among simply connected topological 4-manifolds which are known to admit an exotic smooth structure (as of July 2009).

Are there any more recent results? For example, does $\mathbb{CP}^2$ admit an exotic smooth structure?

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is an open problem. Likewise for $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$.

Comment: If you get no definitive answer here, you should consider migrating this question to MathOverflow.

Comment: These are major open problems, and experts have essentially no opinion what the answer is.